Entry not taking 100% width in horizontallayout .net MAUI
I have this simple grid, isndie the grid i have verticalstacklayout then horizontalstacklayout. In this, entry is not taking 100% width . What i am doing wrong in it.
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,20,20,Auto" Padding="10" ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="8901 PKR" BackgroundColor="Maroon" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="5032 PKR" BackgroundColor="Maroon" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="5032 PKR" BackgroundColor="Maroon" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="5032 PKR" BackgroundColor="Maroon" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
    <!-- Form layout -->
    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <!-- Account Type Row -->
        <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="0,10,0,10" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <Label Text="Account Type" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Entry Text="Account Type" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <!-- Expense Type Row -->
        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <Label Text="Expense Type" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Entry Text="Expense Type" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <!-- Amount Row -->
        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <Label Text="Tota" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Entry Text="" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <!-- Description Row -->
        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <Label Text="Description" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
            <Entry Text="Descr" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <Button Text="Submit" HorizontalOptions="Fill"></Button>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <ListView>
        
    </ListView>
    
    
    
</Grid>


This is as designed, see HorizontalOptions DO NOT Work on HorizontalStackLayout. Try other layout to achieve.

Components in StackLayouts take only the space they need.
You can try using a Grid instead.
<!-- Account Type Row -->
<Grid Padding="0,10,0,10" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *">
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Account Type" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
    <Entry Grid.Column="1" Text="Account Type"></Entry>
</Grid>

P.S. Don't use FillAndExpand anymore. It's deprecated. And Fill is the default value so no need to specify it.

Oh! Is this a right way to create a UI? I mean nested grids or for each form row a new grid?

@MuhammadFaizanKhan yes, you can totally do that. There's nothing that forces you to use only one grid per page (for example, you can also use it as template for CollectionView items). Of course Grid is more complex to render than a HorizontalStackLayout, but in your case (and actually most of cases I've ever seen) I would say it's completely safe.
